# Convincing R that the .dbf file associated with a .shp file is not an executable during command checks

Tags: r, geospatial

I am working on submitting an R package to CRAN. Right now I am trying to reduce the memory footprint of the package. Because this package deals with spatial data that has a very particular format, I want to include a properly formatted shapefile as an example. If I include the full-size original shapefile, there are no warnings (other than file size) in the R CMD checks. However, if I crop the file and include the cropped version in the package (in "inst/extdata") I get this warning:

```
W  checking for executable files (389ms)
   Found the following executable file:
     inst/extdata/temp/temp.dbf
   Source packages should not contain undeclared executable files.
   See section ‘Package structure’ in the ‘Writing R Extensions’ manual.
```

This file is the database file associated with the shapefile. I have tried cropping the file and saving it using `rgdal` functions, `sf` functions, and using QGIS. I have also verified that the modes of the cropped files match the original file using `chmod`. I even tried changing .dbf to .DBF. Does anyone have any additional suggestions, other than listing it in BinaryFiles, which CRAN will not accept in a submission?

I'm running R version 4.0.2 via RStudio 2021.09.1 on Mac OSX 10.15.7. `rgdal` and `sf` are fully updated, as are all of their dependencies.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `/data`, see https://r-pkgs.org/data.html

Comment: `R CMD check` uses the `file` command to determine if a file is executable.  If you open `terminal` on your Mac and run `file inst/extdata/temp/temp.dbf`, what does it report?

Comment: @user2554330 I get "amd 29k coff prebar executable" which certainly explains why it's coming up that way in the check, but now the question is, how do I change this (or crop the file in such a way the .dbf doesn't get saved as an executable). No, @Christoph, I mean `inst/extdata`, as the file I am including is raw, per Wickam's recommendation in the "R Packages" book. "If you want to store raw data, put it in inst/extdata."

Comment: I don't know exactly what `file` is looking for to determine that answer, but a solution might be to compress the file.  Then it would look like a compressed file, not an executable.  You can uncompress it at runtime, or maybe use it directly.

Comment: @HannahO. did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: Yep, I compressed the file per @user2554330's suggestion (added bonus: smaller file size reduced the built package size). I marked Simon Urbanek's answer below as correct though, since it is a more direct solution to the problem, and a helpful explanation as to *why* the problem occurred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known issue[[1]](https://bugs.astron.com/view.php?id=316) where `file` will mis-identify DBF files with last-update date in the year 2022. Easiest fix is to not use a 2022 update date when saving the file. Alternatively you can simply change the second byte of the file after the fact, e.g.:

```r
fn = "myfile.dbf"
sz = file.info(fn)$size
r = readBin(fn, raw(), sz)
r[2] = as.raw(121) ## make it 2021 instead of 2022
writeBin(r, fn)
```

(See also corresponding discussion on [R-package-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2022q1/007722.html))